# Deserialized bean needs scoped dependencies

Tags: java, spring, serialization, jsf, dependency-injection

How can I inject dependencies into a deserialized bean?

Some of my Spring beans should be serialized during the render-response phase of our JSF application, and then deserialized at the beginning of the next request.  Some of those beans have dependencies which are scoped to the request.  If I configure the dependencies with the scoped proxy (`"<aop:scoped-proxy>"`), I can't serialize my dependent beans - the proxy isn't serializable.

So right now we do it by declaring the appropriate member variables of the serialized bean classes as transient, and then calling `context.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().configureBean(bean, name)` just after deserializing the beans - but this sucks, because the bean's initializer is called again.  (As for other dependencies that are in the same scope, are not transient, and are deserialized, I'm not even sure why they don't get overwritten by `configureBean`, but I don't think they are.)

What's better?  Should I just get the bean definition, loop through it, find the dependencies that are scoped to the request, and then call `getBean(name)` on the context?

*(BTW, I'm not sure it makes a difference, but we are using Spring kind of weirdly.  We instantiate a new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext for each non-posted-back HTTP request, rather than a single WebApplicationContext.  Upon postback, we deserialize the beans.  So when I say "scoped to the request", I'm lying; these beans are actually singleton-scoped.  I'd like to use the WebApplicationContext and the more sane scoping with it, but as far as I can tell, that's orthogonal to our problem at the moment.)*

Comment: Instantiating a new context per (some) request can not possibly be the right approach...  What kind of beans are you serializing? What is their purpose? I suspect there is a better design-solution which would eliminate the problem you're facing now (and money others to come if you keep things the way they are)

Comment: It sure seems like the wrong approach - agreed.  It was created when we were integrating, into our system, an app that used Spring.  But the integration seems pretty bass-ackwards.

Comment: Eventually I posted another question on the same issue; and eventually I wrote a solution myself that I posted as an answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3471835/how-to-reattach-singleton-spring-beans-upon-deserialization

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It makes all the difference - I've been using spring with JSF for quite a long time and hadn't had any serialization problems. The way to go is simply define the following in your `faces-config.xml`:

```
<el-resolver>
   org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver
</el-resolver>
```

This integrates spring with JSF by providing spring beans (using the `request` and `session` spring scopes) to JSF pages.

So, I'd advice for changing your approach drastically so that you aren't bug with such problems in the future.

Comment: I'm inclined to abandon the crazy approach we have, and try something a little more orthodox, like what you've described.

Comment: Where in the docs does it say that Spring automatically re-injects the transient @Autowired/@Injected dependencies on de-serialization time? I mean, the image I get is that it only allows calling the Spring beans from the EL?