# how to reattach singleton Spring beans upon deserialization

Tags: java, spring, serialization, dynamic-proxy

I want to reinject singleton-scoped dependencies into prototype Spring beans, after they have been deserialized.

Say I've got a Process bean, which depends on a Repository bean.  The Repository bean is a scoped as a singleton, but the Process bean is prototype-scoped.  Periodically I serialize the Process, and then later deserialize it.

```
class Process {
   private Repository repository;
   // getters, setters, etc.
}
```

I don't want to serialize and deserialize the Repository.  Nor do I want to put "transient" on the member variable that holds a reference to it in Process, nor a reference to some kind of proxy, or anything other than a plain old member variable declared as a Repository.

What I think I want is for the Process to have its dependency filled with a serializable proxy that points (with a transient reference) to the Repository, and, upon deserialization, can find the Repository again.  How could I customize Spring to do that?

I figure I could use a proxy to hold the dependency references, much like .  I wish I could use that exact technique.  But the proxy I've seen Spring generate isn't serializable, and the docs say that if I use it with a singleton bean, I'll get an exception.

I could use a custom scope, perhaps, on the singleton beans, that would always supply a proxy when asked for a custom-scoped bean.  Is that a good idea?  Other ideas?

Comment: What sort of application context are these beans in? A webapp context?

Comment: Right now, not a webapp context.  Later, probably would be a webapp context.

Comment: In that case, how is the context bootstrapped? Is it a desktop application?

Comment: It's a webapp.  The context is bootstrapped via a ServletContextListener.  We have a bit of Spring; I'm trying to add more.  We don't have the spring MVC jars in our path yet, so I'm not using the web app context yet.

Comment: I've posted an answer to my own question, illustrating how I've solved the problem so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about added using aspects to add an injection step when you deserialize the object?

You would need AspectJ or similar for this. It would work very similarly to the @Configurable function in Spring.

e.g. add some advice around the a "private void readObject(ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException" method

This article may also help: http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/serialization/

Comment: I've been resisting aspects because I don't want to rock the boat here, if you know what I mean, but this is an exploratory project, so maybe now's the time.

Still, I'm wondering about other ways to do it.

Answer (score 3):

I used this instead, without any proxy:

```
public class Process implements HttpSessionActivationListener {
    ...
    @Override
    public void sessionDidActivate(HttpSessionEvent e) {
        ServletContext sc = e.getSession().getServletContext();
        WebApplicationContext newContext = WebApplicationContextUtils
            .getRequiredWebApplicationContext(sc);
        newContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().configureBean(this, beanName);
    }
}
```

The example is for a web environment when the application server serializes the session, but it should work for any ApplicationContext.

Answer (score 3):

Spring provides a solution for this problem.

Take a look at the spring documentation http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-atconfigurable.

> 7.8.1 Using AspectJ to dependency inject domain objects with Spring
>
> ...
>
> The support is intended to be used for objects created outside
> of the control of any container. Domain objects often fall into
> this category because they are often created programmatically
> using the new operator, or by an ORM tool as a result of a database query.

The trick is to use load time weaving. Just start the jvm with -javaagent:path/to/org.springframework.instrument-{version}.jar. This agent will recognize every object that is instantiated and if it is annotated with @Configurable it will configure (inject @Autowired or @Resource dependencies) that object.

Just change the Process class to

```
@Configurable
class Process {

   @Autowired
   private transient Repository repository;
   // getters, setters, etc.
}
```

Whenever you create a new instance

```
Process process = new Process();
```

spring will automatically inject the dependencies.
This also works if the Process object is deserialized.

Comment: Why not add the 'transient' keyword to the repository member variable?  Otherwise your Repository class needs to be serializable. , but I don't see why you would want to serialize it.

Answer (score 1):

I think the idea of serializing a bean and then forcing a reinjection of dependencies is not the best architecture.

How about having some sort of ProcessWrapper bean instead which could be a singleton.  It would be injected with the Repository and either manages the deserialization of the Process or has a setter for it.  When a new Process is set in the wrapper, it would call `setRepository()` on the Process.  The beans that use the Process could either be set with the new one by the wrapper or call the ProcessWrapper which would delegate to the Process.

```
class ProcessWrapper {
   private Repository repository;
   private Process process;
   // getters, setters, etc.

   public void do() {
      process.do();
   }

   public void setProcess(Process process) {
      this.process = process;
      this.process.setRepository(repository);
   }
}
```

Comment: But how would `RepositoryFactory` work? It has to be serializable, and so cannot have a reference to the application context. It just pushes the problem around.

Comment: Process and Repository are just examples (and Process is a bad example; sorry about that).  The beans that are being deserialized, in general, are controllers that manage a particular interaction between the user and our webapp.  There are many of them, and there are always more to write.  They consume many different services.

Comment: Do/can they all implement the same interface?  Can you then write a proxy wrapper which implements that interface and delegates to each of them in turn.  If they are all different then I agree that this solution is cumbersome.

Comment: Why is it not a good idea/architecture to automatically reinject the lost dependencies on deserialization time?

Comment: I means that you have to duplicate a lot of functionality that spring already does into hand code.  How do you find the appropriate beans to auto-inject, ....  Plus there are a number of features in Spring that wouldn't be duplicated since this bean wouldn't _really_ be in the context.  I thought a manager wrapper would be a better idea.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question: how I've solved the problem so far is to create a base class which serializes and deserializes using a cheap little proxy.  The proxy contains only the name of the bean.

You'll note that it uses a global to access the Spring context; a more elegant solution might store the context in a thread-local variable, something like that.

```
public abstract class CheaplySerializableBase 
   implements Serializable, BeanNameAware {

    private String name;

    private static class SerializationProxy implements Serializable {

        private final String name;

        public SerializationProxy(CheaplySerializableBase target) {
            this.name = target.name;
        }

        Object readResolve() throws ObjectStreamException {
            return ContextLoader.globalEvilSpringContext.getBean(name);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void setBeanName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    protected Object writeReplace() throws ObjectStreamException {
        if (name != null) {
            return new SerializationProxy(this);
        }
        return this;
    }
}
```

The resulting serialized object is 150 bytes or so (if I remember correctly).

Answer (score 0):

The method `applicationContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().autowireBean(detachedBean);` can be used to reconfigure a Spring-managed bean that was serialized and then de-serialized (whose `@Autowired` fields become `null`). See example below. The serialization details are omitted for simplicity.

```
public class DefaultFooService implements FooService {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext ctx;

    @Override
    public SerializableBean bar() {
        SerializableBean detachedBean = performAction();
        ctx.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().autowireBean(detachedBean);
        return detachedBean;
    }

    private SerializableBean performAction() {
        SerializableBean outcome = ... // Obtains a deserialized instance, whose @Autowired fields are detached.
        return outcome;
    }

}


public class SerializableBean {

    @Autowired
    private transient BarService barService;

    private int value;

    public void doSomething() {
        barService.doBar(value);
    }

}
```